# php conditional statement not giving supposed result

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

My code below is supposed to display the last statement if the date expiry date is less than current date but it is instead showing second statement acting as though the expiry date is greater than the current date. I tested with a code that expired since01-12-2013 but it is still showing that the client have active discount. Please help point out where I might have made mistake.

```
<?php if ($totalRows_coupon == 0) { ?>
<table width="96%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000" class="hint style2">
<div align="center" class="style3">You have entered an invalid discount 
        code. Leave blank if you don't have any.</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <?php } else { if ($row_coupon['type']=='percentage' && date("d-m-Y") < strtotime("$edate") && $row_coupon['status']=='active') {?>
<table width="96%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFCCCC" class="hint"> 
      <div align="center">You have a <span class="style1"><?php echo $row_coupon['value']; ?>%</span> 
        discount valid for <?php if ($row_coupon['freq'] == 888) {
    echo "<font color=black>unlimited</font>";}else {
    echo $row_coupon['freq'];}?> uses. You have <?php if ($row_coupon['freq'] == 888) {
    echo "<font color=black>unlimited</font>";}else {
    echo $row_coupon['rem'];}?> 
        uses left to expire on <?php echo $row_coupon['eDate']; ?> </div></td>
      <input name="coupon" type="hidden" id="coupon" value="<?php echo $row_coupon['value']; ?>"/>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <?php }elseif (date("d-m-Y") > strtotime("$edate") OR $row_coupon['status']!='active') { ?>
  <table width="96%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000" class="hint style2">
<div align="center" class="style3">This discount code have expired since <?php echo $row_coupon['eDate']; ?>. Please enter an active code or leave blank.</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php  }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered, I have corrected my mistakes, learned my lessons and it is working now. Am so excited!

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing apples and oranges:

```
date("d-m-Y") < strtotime("$edate")
```

`date()` returns a **STRING** representing the date in the specified format, e.g. `04-01-2014`.
`strtotime()` returns an **INTEGER** - a unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

In other words, your code boils down to

```
if('04-01-2014' < 523423423)  // picking out some random timstamp value
```

Since you're comparing strings to ints, the string will be converted to an int, resulting in `4`, and you end up with

```
if (4 < 523423423)
```

which is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else if` statement has a few issues:

```
elseif (date("d-m-Y") > strtotime("$edate") OR $row_coupon['status'] != 'active') {
```

First the output of `date("d-m-Y")` and `strtotime("$edate")` are not the same since `date` will give you human readable time and `strtotime` gives you a Unix timestamp.  To do a  comparison you should simply use [`time`](https://www.php.net/time).  Here is my fixes & cleanup with additional notes below.

```
elseif ((time() > strtotime("$edate")) || ($row_coupon['status'] != 'active')) {
```

In addition to using `time()` for the check, I have corrected the use of the word `OR` to be a true PHP logical “OR” operator of `||`. Read more about PHP logical operators [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Also, I have contained each condition in parenthesis—`(` and `)`—as well. Even though this is a simply double-check in the condition, it can be easier to read, parse & debug if clearly delineated like this.

Answer (score -3):

```
$row_coupon['status']!='active'
```

should be

```
$row_coupon['status']!=='active'
```

double equals - otherwise you will set it and make it true - and it will fulfill the OR part of the statement.

Comment: -1. totally wrong. `!=` is a perfectly valid comparison operation. if it was `=`, then yes, it would be an assignment. `!==` is the STRICT inequality operation - type AND value are compared.

Comment: yes yes I know - jeez its 6:15am here on a Sunday - cut me some slack :-P - I should have taken my time - I spotted something at a glance in some messy code that I THOUGHT would mess it up and posted, give a tired little soldier a break :-D